# NHibernate 3.1 nested where clause using LINQ doesn't create proper SQL

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following Nhibernate LINQ query:

```
var query = from c in session.Query<Customer>()
            where
                c.EmailAddress == customer.EmailAddress ||
                (
                    c.Address1 == customer.Address1 &&
                    c.City == customer.City &&
                    c.State == customer.State &&
                    c.Postal == customer.Postal &&
                    c.FirstName == customer.FirstName &&
                    c.LastName == customer.LastName
                )
                select c;
```

I expected the resulting SQL statement to look like:

```
select
    ...
from
    dbo.Customers customer0_ 
where
    customer0_.EmailAddress=@p0 or 
    (
        customer0_.Address1=@p1 
        and customer0_.City=@p2 
        and customer0_.State=@p3 
        and customer0_.Postal=@p4 
        and customer0_.FirstName=@p5 
        and customer0_.LastName=@p6;
    )
```

But what I see from the debug log is:

```
select
    ...
from
    dbo.Customers customer0_ 
where
    customer0_.EmailAddress=@p0 
    or customer0_.Address1=@p1 
    and customer0_.City=@p2 
    and customer0_.State=@p3 
    and customer0_.Postal=@p4 
    and customer0_.FirstName=@p5 
    and customer0_.LastName=@p6;
```

Notice there is no grouping on the address part of the where clause. Is this intentional? Should I be formatting my query a different way, or is this a bug?

Comment: I suspect you need to upgrade to 3.2 (or latest from trunk) as 3.1 linq was not fully featured.

Comment: The assembly with this code was referencing 3.1 (came with Fluent Nhibernate nuget package), but the main project was referencing 3.2, with a binding redirect, so the actual live code should have been using 3.2, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping in condition is being dropped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297235/grouping-in-condition-is-being-dropped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated SQL is correct; the parentheses are not needed.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but thanks for including the link in the comments that explains exactly why.